# Retrieving Copy_to/Stored fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I had created a copy_to field as of an existing field by altering its mapping below:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "ExistingField": {
      "type": "date",
      "copy_to": "CopiedField"
    },
    "CopiedField": {
      "type": "date",
      "store": true
    }
  }
}
```

I had used "store": "true" since I wanted this new fields value to be retrieved when I do a search. Aggregations with the "CopiedField" work fine but when I try to search for a value in this new CopiedField I cannot see anything being retrieved:

```
{
  "stored_fields": [
      "CopiedField"
     ],
  "query": {
  "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

How do I retrieve the value of this "CopiedField" in a simple search?

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue and I am getting below response "fields" : {
          "CopiedField" : [
            "2019-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"
          ]
        } Can you paste your response

Comment: For some reason I was never able to retrieve the value of this stored field. Did you add documents to the Index after creating the mapping?

Comment: Yes , I added docs after creating mapping. Can  you add your data , full query and rresponse

Comment: It does not work for documents before the mapping. After the mapping any documents added are retrieved perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapping cannot be changed for already existing fields.
You will need to create a new index(with correct mapping) and move documents from old index to new index. You can delete old index and use alias so that index name is not changed

1. (Mapping)[https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime]
2. (Reindex)[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html]
3. (Alias)[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-aliases.html]
   ex.

Old index index35 with below mapping

```
PUT index35
{
  "mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "ExistingField": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Query: below query will not return anything

```
GET index35/_search
{
  "stored_fields": [
    "CopiedField"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Create New index

```
PUT index36
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ExistingField": {
        "type": "date",
        "copy_to": "CopiedField"
      },
      "CopiedField": {
        "type": "date",
        "store": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Move old documents to new documents

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "index35"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index36"  ----> must be created before reindex
  }
}
```

**Make sure document count is same in both old and new index(to prevent data loss)**

Delete old index :-DELETE index35

Create an alias for new index(give old name) so that search queries are not affected

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add" : { "index" : "index36", "alias" : "index35" } }
    ]
}
```

Old query will now return results